# How do I calculate the total and average of all dice rolls?

Tags: python

I am 100% new to coding. This is my first semester in IT and Python is making 0% sense to me at all. This is the assignment I have been given:

Code this program as a while statement,
then create it a second time as a for statement

Ask the user how many times she will roll the 2 dice.
Simulate the dice roll that many times by generating 2 random numbers between 1 and 6
Immediately after each roll display the total of the roll
After all of the rolls calculate and display:
-the total of all of the rolls
-the average of all of the rolls

Use meaningful variable names
Comment the main sections of your code and any lines that aren't self-explanatory

Your program output should look like this:

How many times will you roll the dice? 2
You rolled a 1 and a 5
You rolled a 3 and a 6
Your total for all of the rolls is 15
You average for all of the rolls is 7.5

This is what I have so far, but I have spent hours reading our text-book chapters and watching recordings of the lecture and I can not figure out the rest. Please help.

```
from random import randint

numRolls= int(input("How many times will you roll the dice? "))

for diceRolls in range(numRolls):
    d1 = randint(1,6)
    d2 = randint(1,6)
    print("You rolled a", d1, "and a",d2)
    
print("Your total for all of the rolls is", )

print("Your average for all of the rolls is", )
```

Comment: 1. How do you calculate the total (=sum) of two numbers (a roll of your two dice), and how do you display it?
2. How do you store the total number (=sum) of all dice rolls (or any number)?
3. How do you calculate the average of a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list to store the data. You can also use the sum function to get the sum of all the values in the list, and use `sum(allDiceRolls)/len(allDiceRolls)` to get the average

Code:

```py
from random import randint

numRolls = int(input("How many times will you roll the dice? "))

allDiceRolls = []

for diceRolls in range(numRolls):
    d1 = randint(1,6)
    d2 = randint(1,6)
    allDiceRolls.append(d1)
    allDiceRolls.append(d2)
    print("You rolled a", d1, "and a",d2)
    
print("Your total for all of the rolls is", sum(allDiceRolls))

print("Your average for all of the rolls is", sum(allDiceRolls)/len(allDiceRolls))
```

Comment: if my answer helped you out, please check the checkmark and upvote

Comment: You don't really need to store all the values in the list. You can just have a sum variable and add d1 and d2 to sum after each iteration.

Comment: @AdityaKurkure, correct, but I happened to use lists

Answer (score 1):

Without using lists and additional memory:

```py
from random import randint


numRolls = int(input("How many times will you roll the dice? "))
s = 0

for roll in range(numRolls):
    d1 = randint(1, 6)
    d2 = randint(1, 6)
    s += d1 + d2
    print("You rolled a", d1, "and a", d2)
    
print("Your total for all of the rolls is", s)
print("Your average for all of the rolls is", s / numRolls)
```